# Sed/RegEx: Removing block of code between two strings from PHP file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've been trying to remove a block of code from a PHP file with sed, that is between these two tags: **//istart** and **//iend**. The code between the tags, and the tags themselves, should be deleted. The idea is to do it recursively, so I can do it for several files.

So, I've got this RegEx: `/\/\/istart([\s\S]*?)\/\/iend/`.

You can check it working here: https://regex101.com/r/sQ2bA0/2

However, when I run *sed* command, nothing happens to the file. I've already tried it in several ways, always without success.

- `sed -i 's/istart([\s\S]*?)\/\/iend//g' test.php`
- `sed -i '1s/\/\/istart([\s\S]*?)\/\/iend//' test.php`

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/\/\/istart/,/\/\/iend/{s/\/\/istart.*$//p; s/^.*\/\/iend//p; d;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

CarlosMaia!

Try with this:

```
"\/\/istart{1,}(.*\n)+.*\/\/iend"
```

But you need have a 1 line between "//istart" and "//iend"

Best regards!!